# Calculating Confidence Interval with log-transformation

Tags: multiple-regression, confidence-interval, interaction, validity

I fitted a linear regression with a 3rd order interaction and adjustment for confounding variable which looks like this:

$$
log(Y) = β_1S + β_2T + β_3M + β_4ST + β_5SM + β_6TM + β_7STM + β_XX
$$

With $Y$ my outcome, $S$, $T$ and $M$ my interesting variables and $X$ my vector of confounding variables.

I have got MLE and standard deviation for every β.

By transformation, I can get back to Y like this:

$$
Y={e^{β_1 } }^S×{e^{β_2 } }^T×{e^{β_3 } }^M×{e^{β_4 } }^{ST}×{e^{β_5 } }^{SM}×{e^{β_6 } }^{TM}×{e^{β_7 } }^{STM}×e^{β_XX}
$$

This form is quite harder to interpret than the additive form for non-stat experts (which my study is aiming at).

In order to simplify interpretations, I thought about computing the increase of $Y$ depending only on $S$, $T$ and $M$, which I'd think would take this form (since $β_XX$ contains intercept and confounding variables):

$$
\begin{align}
& Y'= Y × coef _{(S, T, M)} \\
& coef = {e^{β_1 } }^S×{e^{β_2 } }^T×{e^{β_3 } }^M×{e^{β_4 } }^{ST}×{e^{β_5 } }^{SM}×{e^{β_6 } }^{TM}×{e^{β_7 } }^{STM}
\end{align}
$$

This coefficient is easy to compute and to interpret as the effect of $S$, $T$ and $M$ on $Y$ for anyone, but

- Is it valid ? Else, is it possible to compute something similar ?
- How to compute its confidence interval ? (wouldn't it even be a prediction interval in this case ?)

Feel free to ask for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid.

To computer the CI for $coef$, the covariances between $\hat\beta_i$ and $\hat\beta)j$ are needed.
We have $$Var(S\hat\beta_1 + T\hat\beta_2 + ...+ STM\hat\beta_7) = S^2Var(\hat\beta_1) + ...+ (STM)^2Var(\hat\beta_7) + 2STCov(\hat\beta_1,\hat\beta_2) + ... + 2ST^2M^2Cov(\hat\beta_6,\hat\beta_7)$$

Then get the CI of $S\hat\beta_1 + T\hat\beta_2 + ...+ STM\hat\beta_7$ by $S\hat\beta_1 + T\hat\beta_2 + ...+ STM\hat\beta_7 +/- Z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{Var(S\hat\beta_1 + T\hat\beta_2 + ...+ STM\hat\beta_7)}$

Then Exponential of them are the CI of $coef$.

If you are familiar with matrix, it is simpler in matrix in writing and in calculation.

Let $\hat β_1S + \hat β_2T + \hat β_3M + \hat β_4ST + \hat β_5SM + \hat β_6TM + \hat β_7STM = (S, T, M, ST, SM, TM, STM)(\hat β_1,\hat β_2,\hat β_3,\hat β_4,\hat β_5,\hat β_6,\hat β_7)' = A\hat\beta$

Then $Var(A\hat\beta) = ACov(\hat\beta)A'$, where $Cov(\hat\beta)$ is variance-covariance matrix of $\hat\beta$ and should be able to get its estimate from the model fitting software.

It seems Excel can perform this kind of matrix operation.

Comment: This is far beyond my level in maths, but your answer looks like the [variance of a weighted sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Weighted_sum_of_variables). But since I have interactions, is it OK not to include [variance of products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Product_of_statistically_dependent_variables) ? Are not $S, T$ and $M$ random variable in this case ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My answer is the same as variance of a weighted sum. In your situation, $\hat\beta$s are random variables. Others are constants. Because you have interactions, the covariances is more important. So totally you have 28 terms (7 variance and 21 covariance).

Comment: Great, thanks a lot ! I'll wait a bit to accept the answer, in case someone want to contradict you :-)

Comment: Matrix form were added. If you can manipulate the matrix, it will be easy.

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot. Could you provide a reference to the last formula you used for $Var(A\beta)$? This is not the first time I see it and I would like to understand it better.

Comment: $Var(A\beta)$ is the exact same as you mentioned variance of a weighted sum, in the different form. One is scalar, another is matrix.